# What should i do with BJT when BJT has other two pins

Tags: bjt, spice

The commomn BJT has three pin for B,E and C,but i use the virtuoso to choose bjt504tnpn from analoglib and find it has five pin,i surf the Internet,
guessing these five pin is B,C,E,S and Th,however,i don't know what is Th here,and also wonder what should i do with S and Th when i want to make the schematic below
[image]
[image]

Comment: Pick a sane model instead?

Comment: But i have only this kind of BJT in the virtuoso

Comment: Virtuoso has a very large amount of documentation packaged with every install. This documentation includes a description of each of the blocks in analoglib. Consult this documentation in order to determine the mapping of the pinout to the device pins.

Comment: I addition, Virtuoso is meant to be used with PDK models from the fab you will be using. I've never used active devices from the analoglib. Perhaps, you should be looking at other libraries to find the proper devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect that:

S = substrate connection, the connection to the substrate on which the NPN transistor is made.

and

Th = a "thermal" connection, to be used for thermal simulations. For example, if the BJT is 300 Kelvin, that pin would carry 300 V DC (I'm guessing here, to be sure read the library's documentation).

I suggest that you use a different BJT, look in the AnalogLib library, there are generic NPNs there.

Or if you **must** use this model, do not connect the pins, place a noConn (from the basic library) on both pins so that the "not connected" warning goes away.

Answer (score 1):

You're using Mextram 504 model, which models the vertical bjts

[image]

C, B, E are of course collector, base and emitter. S is the substrate.

According to [this guide](https://www.nxp.com/wcm_documents/models/bipolar-models/mextram/MXT_syntax.pdf) and [the model guide](http://www.eng.auburn.edu/~niuguof/mextram/_downloads/MextramDefinition.pdf), the fifth terminal (there called dt) is the self-heating terminal. This is modeled as follows:

[image]

You can either just measure it (the voltage being the self-heating induced temperature variation) or you can even connect to other elements, e.g. to simulate for instance mutual heating (see, for instance, Fig. 22 of [this link](https://www.nxp.com/wcm_documents/models/bipolar-models/mextram/nlur2002806.pdf)).

To remove those two additional terminals, you could use bjtd504npn (notice the "d" and the absence of "t").

[image]